# How to create a dynamic tile portfolio?

Tags: jquery, web, tile, portfolio

I wanted to know what is the way of creating a tile-based portfolio like this:

http://prothemeus.com/demo/litho/

I mean I know it must be a mixed thing of jQuery and CSS3 and stuff... I wanted to know how should I create one!

Thanks in advance

Comment: you're going to get down voted for this one. It's not exactly a question. Asking vaguely "How do I build a web site like this" is a wide open question. 

I think you're on the right track though. HTML5/CSS3/jQuery

Comment: I agree with @hunter, however just this once: it's a jQuery library called isotope. Here's the link: isotope.metafizzy.co

Comment: 1. Press F12. 
2. Open Sources (Scripts) tab.
3...
4. Profit

Comment: fyi, I found that by quickly viewing their source code

Comment: thanks for your comments, I'll appreciate any sort of guides on this.

sorry bad for question anyway.

Comment: just visited isotope's website, that's the answer I think :D @Mike Robinson thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is a 1d bin-packing algorithm and it can be useful to minimize bins in operation research. What's also interesting is that it orders the tiles in columns (x-axis). Css alone can only orders in rows (y-axis).  There are a lot of jquery plugins adding this function to html and css available for download for example masonry, wookmark and a lots more. Isotope is the big sister of masonry and has a slightly tigther license.

Comment: thanks dude. checking em out <3